# CSS does not work in JSP, when is placed in a file. Why is it so?

Tags: java, css, jsp

I have tried it using `<style>` and everything works fine, but when I link to CSS in a file - it does not work at all.
If hover my mouse over the path in Intellij Idea - it can see the file.
Here is my JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <title>Meals List</title>
</head>


<body>
<table class="styled-table">
<caption>Meals with Date, Description and Calories</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Calories</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="meal" items="${requestScope.meals}">
        <jsp:useBean id="meal" scope="page" type="ru.javawebinar.topjava.model.MealTo"/>

        <tr class="${meal.excess ? 'exceeded' : 'notExceeded'}">
            <td><%=ru.javawebinar.topjava.util.TimeUtil.formatLocalDateTime(meal.getDateTime(),"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm")%></td>
            <td> ${meal.description}</td>
            <td> ${meal.calories}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my project structure:

[image]

Comment: @Alohci, Could you please clarify what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move it outside "WEB-INF" folder first. Next step is simpy calling

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

If it must be in "WEB-INF" just add directory as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WEB-INF/css/style.css"/>
```

Comment: It should stay in WEB-INF, I have tried everything you wrote but it does not help :(

Comment: did you try with application.contextPath instead of pageContext? Altough it should work either way.

Comment: It is best for you to try getting path of css in browser. For example: http://localhost:8080/yourContextPath/css/styles.css . Then just ".../../css/styles.css" to applications.contextPath